# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS in Laravel

Tags: laravel, routes, http-status-code-302

I am learning Laravel. I have a problem with the very basics. I get a  ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

my routes.php:

```
Route::get('/','WelcomeController@index');
```

index function:

```
public function index(){
    return view('welcome');
}
```

The URL gets an additional part, I don't know why.

From http://localhost/dev.todoparrot.com/public to http://localhost/dev.todoparrot.com/public/home

```
<?php

namespace todoparrot\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use todoparrot\Http\Requests;
use todoparrot\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class WelcomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(){
        return view('welcome');
    }


    public function contact(){
        echo "we are in contacts";
        return view('welcome');
    }


    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: The code looks fine to me. There is probably issue with server configuration.  Show us some server (apache/nginx)  code snippets...

Comment: Do you have any middleware configured?

Comment: Can you share your WelcomeController's constructor code?

Comment: I addedd the whole WelcomeController code. izupet, I don't think server configuration is the problem, because I have a different Laravel project on this server as well and it works just fine. I probably made some stupid typo or something. I didn't do anything in the middleware folder, Mina.

Comment: The controller looks fine. Can you share your htacess & full routes file?

Comment: hey, did you solve it? i have the same problem